# How to "pull upstream" using SVN

Tags: svn, version-control

Is there a way to perform an operation similar to `pull upstream` in git/mercurial using Subversion?

Basically I need to get two repositories in sync with each other - maybe, svnsync is a way to go? BTW, I don't need backup capabilities, which afaik is the main purpose of svnsync.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preface**

1. Don't use CVCS in DVCS style - it'll give you a lot of headache and wasted time
2. Svnsync isn't backup tool (just because backup of *some tree on FS* of server can be done more easier with special backup-tool **and** because svnsync'ed repo is not full backup of all repository-related data: except repo per se it's also auth-data, ACLs etc...), but (as expected) uni-directional mirror

**Face**

If you want to have in sync not only HEAD-states, but also full history, you have single (IMNSHO) pure SVN-way: exchange of (incremental) dumps (`svnadmin dump|load` or `svnrdump dump|load`) and cooperation and assistance from SVN-admins on both nodes: you can't load into repo anything without help and appropriate rights

Answer (score 0):

To get 2 repos in sync, use svnsync... its an incremental sync tool that will replay commits to one repo to another and is very easy to regularly run to mirror commits to keep a backup repo in sync.

If your repos are all over the place though with separate commits to both, then you are going to have to do more work, I'd recommend syncing from both to a 3rd repo and then use that.